# Keep image not rotation when skew?

Tags: html, css

I want to cut small element in an image. So, I am using `skew` to do this.

But when to skew, the image seems broken,  I want to keep image is not rotation.

My code like this:

```css
.image-skew{
/*   transform: skewX(-25deg); */
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.img-skew-invest {
  transform: skewX(-25deg);
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-skew">
  <img class="img-skew-invest" src="http://thebusiness.vn/uploads/business360/chuyenkinhdoanh/lazada-co-noi-got-foodpanda-roi-khoi-viet-nam/lazada-co-noi-got-foodpanda-roi-khoi-viet-nam.png" alt="" style="width: 100%; height: auto"/>
</div>
```

Same image.

I cut an element of the picture with skew, but it should be a not rotation.

[image]

Comment: The question is super vague. Can you elaborate more ?

Comment: `skew` is doing exactly what it was supposed to do. I don't understand what you expected of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clip-path` will match your requirement:

```
.image-skew {
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(25% 0, 100% 0, 100% 75%, 75% 100%, 0 100%, 0% 25%);
clip-path: polygon(25% 0, 100% 0, 100% 75%, 75% 100%, 0 100%, 0% 25%);
}
```

Try it yourself: https://jsfiddle.net/hgzsr5f5/1/ or try **clip-path generator**: http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: Your answer resolved my problem. 
It useful. Thanks, @jaredchu.